# MongoDB Aggregator - grouping unique items that occur within 30 seconds of each other

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Problem I'm trying to solve**:
I have a set of documents in MongoDB that represent moments when a user enters and exits a page. My goal is to group these into "sessions".

**Define Session**: A session is any unique chunks of documents that occur within 30 seconds of each other. They are unique if they have the same `uid`, `documentId`, and `clientType`.

#### The goal is to turn this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "interactionType": "pageEnter",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:22.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "interactionType": "pageExit",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:32.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "interactionType": "pageEnter",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0/a",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:42.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "interactionType": "pageExit",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0/a",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:52.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "interactionType": "pageEnter",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:03:42.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "interactionType": "pageExit",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "clientType": "web",
        "routePath": "/d0",
        "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:03:52.000Z"
    }
]
```

#### Into this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "d0-u0-web-2020-06-12T17:00:42.000Z",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "lastViewedAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:42.000Z",
        "totalDurationMilli": 20000,
        "history": [
            {
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "totalDurationMilli": 10000
            },
            {
                "routePath": "/d0/a",
                "clientType": "web",
                "totalDurationMilli": 10000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "d0-u0-web-2020-06-12T17:03:42.000Z",
        "uid": "u0",
        "documentId": "d0",
        "lastViewedAt": "2020-06-12T17:03:42.000Z",
        "totalDurationMilli": 10000,
        "history": [
            {
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "totalDurationMilli": 10000
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Notice that both "session" documents have the same `documentId`, but different groups of history they are based from. This is because, as noted earlier, I want to separate the data in such a way that each session is at least 30 seconds apart.

#### So far my aggregator looks like this:

```
[
    // Filter by pageEnter and pageExit
    { $match: { interactionType: { $in: ['pageEnter', 'pageExit'] } } },

    // Sort by occurredAt
    { $sort: { occurredAt: 1 } },

    // Group by special id and and compose history.
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                uid: '$uid',
                documentId: '$documentId',
                clientType: '$clientType',
            },
            history: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
        },
    },

    // Project fields for final document.
    {
        $project: {
            _id: { $concat: ['$_id.documentId', '-', '$_id.uid', '-', '$_id.clientType', '-', { $arrayElemAt: ['$history.occurredAt', 0] }] },
            uid: { $arrayElemAt: ['$history.uid', 0] },
            documentId: { $arrayElemAt: ['$history.documentId', 0] },
            lastViewedAt: { $arrayElemAt: ['$history.occurredAt', 0] },
            totalDurationMilli: 'unknown',
            history: 1,
        },
    },
]
```

#### Which spits out this ([mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b-lfjb1OQTl)):

```
    {
        _id: "d0-u0-web-2020-06-12T17:00:22.000Z",
        uid: "u0",
        documentId: "d0",
        lastViewedAt: "2020-06-12T17:00:22.000Z",
        totalDurationMilli: 'unknown',
        history: [
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "interactionType": "pageEnter",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:22.560Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "interactionType": "pageExit",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:32.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "interactionType": "pageEnter",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0/a",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:42.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "4",
                "interactionType: "pageExit",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0/a",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:00:52.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5",
                "interactionType": "pageEnter",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:03:42.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6",
                "interactionType": "pageExit",
                "uid": "u0",
                "documentId": "d0",
                "clientType": "web",
                "routePath": "/d0",
                "occurredAt": "2020-06-12T17:03:52.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

My biggest issue is I can't figure out how to actually group these items correctly. Are there any specific helpers I can use to solve this?

Comment: Not clear why first expected `_id` points to `17:00:42`, when it should be: `17:00:22`. That's what I've tried https://mongoplayground.net/p/wz6oiUtA-5P